# How to change encoding of multiple csv files with different default encoding types?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of `.csv` files that have different encoding types - some of them could be opened such as:

```
pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding="cp1251", sep=";")
```

while for other files `pd.read_csv(filepath)` works nicely.

---

Merging two dataframes with different encoding on a column with Cyrillic text values is a pain.

How do I set `utf-8` encoding for those files that are encoded as `cp1251`?

Comment: Couldn’t you read the file using the current encoding, change the encoding of the contents, and write it back to file?

Comment: @AMC, thanks for the suggestion. Apparently it did change the csv's encoding, but not the text characters written in Ukrainian. I probably should've phrased my question differently